# How to make user interest prediction for article reading

Tags: pandas, time-series, data-science, prediction, xgboost

I am trying to get user interest prediction on the daily articles read for an website by using below sample data :

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sdate = date(2019,1,1)   # start date
edate = date(2019,1,7)   # end date -6days

required_dates = pd.date_range(sdate,edate-timedelta(days=1),freq='d')
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['2019-01-01', 1000,101], ['2019-01-03', 1000,201] ,['2019-01-02', 1500,301], 
        ['2019-01-02', 1400,101],['2019-01-04', 1500,201],['2019-01-01', 2000,201],
        ['2019-01-04', 2000,101],['2019-01-04', 1400,301],['2019-01-05', 1400,301],['2019-01-05', 1400,301]]
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['OnlyDate', 'ArticleID','UserID'])
df1=df1[['OnlyDate','UserID','ArticleID']]
df1.sort_values(by=['UserID','ArticleID'],inplace=True)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
# raw data 
raw_data= df1

# Final Data
final_data= (df1.groupby(['OnlyDate','UserID','ArticleID'])
    .size()
    .unstack('OnlyDate', fill_value=0) 
    .unstack('UserID', fill_value=0)
    .unstack()
    .reset_index(name='InterestValue'))
```

My Data looks like :

[image]

Now I am using XGB model :

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, train_test_split
# converting data for model
final_data['OnlyDate']=pd.to_datetime(final_data['OnlyDate'],format="%Y-%m-%d")
final_data['OnlyDate']= final_data['OnlyDate'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
final_data['OnlyDate']=final_data['OnlyDate'].astype(np.int64)
final_data.info()
# splitting data
X, y = final_data.drop('InterestValue',axis=1), final_data.InterestValue
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=44)
print(X.shape,y.shape,X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Accuracy of XGB classifier on training set: {:.2f}'
       .format(xgb_model.score(X_train, y_train)))
print('Accuracy of XGB classifier on test set: {:.2f}'
       .format(xgb_model.score(X_test[X_train.columns], y_test)))
#making prediction here 
y_pred = xgb_model.predict(X_test)
#Checking how data looks after prediction
X_test_afterPrediction = X_test.copy()
X_test_afterPrediction['InterestValue']= y_test
X_test_afterPrediction['PredictedValues'] = y_pred
X_test_afterPrediction
```

Prediction output looks like :

[image]

Currently with my original dataset I am getting only **20%** prediction were correct.
Let me know which are the other ways or models I should use to improve my prediction rate?

**Edit:**  with LSTM multivariante I am able to predict for single user data at a time with 28% prediction rate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a really really broad question, did you do EDA? Because my first question would be what's the distribution for InterestValue. And further than that, what is the distribution on ANY of those data fields.

If interestvalues are mostly zeros then the model is going to fit more zeros, in that case, stratification in your sampling will help a lot, is it a binary prediction or multiclass?

Also, what sort of tuning did you do on this model, it looks like it's just the default hyperparameters.